# SVN Multiple Branches with "Dependencies"

Tags: svn, deployment, version-control

I'm currently facing the following situation:

I have an SVN Repository with the trunk, where some developers continue to add code (as it is supposed to)

Then we have different branches (see picture) p1_test (a testing system) and p1_live (a production system).

The procedure we want is to update the p1_test branch from trunk (process v¹) every X days.
Then the "real files" in the working copy from p1_test will be updated (v²).

System p1_test is than tested and every bugfix is (or should be) committed to p1_test branch and the p1_test system is updated (v² again). 
Meanwhile other developers that are not involved in the p1-cycle will continue to add to trunk. These changes should **not** be integrated in p1_test branch (yet).

Finally (when p1_test) is considered stable, the branch p1_live should be updated from the p1_test branch and all changes done to p1_test should be reintegrated to trunk (v³).

On a given point of time v⁴ is executed, meaning the working copy of p1_live is updated from the p1_live branch.

Even though everything should be tested fine, we must have the option to "hotfix" anything going heavily wrong on p1_live. In this case changes are directly done to the p1_live branch and the system is updated from this branch (v⁵).

This process must work concurrently with an unknown number of pX_test and pX_live system.

[image: Svn Branching Schema]

is this even possible using svn?
Currently I am facing a lot of problems with different revision numbers, conflicts etc.

Is there a version control system that would allow me to follow the given procedure?

Kind regards,
Timetrick

Answer (score 5):

We use Subversion for a large active codebase with a similar usage pattern to yours. We have the standard trunk/branches/tags base hierarchy. In branches we have `unstable`, `testing`, and `stable`. We also have "user" branches with a folder per username in the branches folder. Tags are exactly how they should be: An untouchable snapshot.

```
trunk

branches/unstable
branches/testing
branches/stable
branches/userA/branch1
branches/userA/branch2
...

tags/stable/rNNNN
tags/stable/vN.N.N.N
...
```

- With all my experience using Subversion, I have found it works so much
  better if code flows in **one direction only**. The exception is
  creating a branch from trunk, which is of course okay to merge
  changes back into trunk once the branch is complete (commonly termed "reintegrating" a branch).
- If code cannot flow in one direction, then it must at least **stay on one path**.
  That means a branch of a branch should never reintegrate directly back into
  trunk, for example.
- Our usage pattern follows that all active development, including bug fixes,
  always finds its way into trunk first, and then trunk is the update provider
  for the unstable, testing, and stable branches. (It would also be okay to 
  follow a `trunk -> unstable -> testing -> stable` merge path, but we don't 
  due to reasons specific to our testing/release process.)
- If you have a fix for a  specific branch, then make it there and do not plan to 
  merge it back into trunk. My experience has discovered that is a great way to 
  accidentally have an innocent branch update break code or even remove code from
  trunk that simply had not been provided to the branch, yet.

You might gather from my points that Subversion requires a process to really use it effectively as you want to (and we do), and to avoid those odd conflicts that leave you saying "now what?" Everything you are describing and trying to figure out sounds all too familiar to me regarding Subversion.

I have often considered if the hype around DVCS tools like Git or Mercurial not having these problems (at all??) would be worth the time it would take to migrate our repositories (hundreds) over. The only thing stopping me from trying is time constraints, but you might be in a better position to give one of those tools a try.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I changed to GIT.

Thanks to [this wonderful blog post](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) I got it up and running. 
(It does all I require it to do, and even more...)